# Recalling words from external files and using them as values

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am trying to read words off of a .txt file to determine the order of functions in my script. It reads the line correctly but does not actually do what it is supposed to. any help would be much appreciated, as I am at a loss for where the problem even starts.

```
    settings_file = open('Settings.txt', 'r')
    homescreen_order_string_1 = ['assignments ']
    homescreen_order_string_2 = ['checklists ']
    homescreen_order_string_3 = ['custom text ']

    lines = settings_file.readlines()
    lines_to_read_1 = [3]

    def readline(lines):
        if lines in homescreen_order_string_1:
            return "assignments"
        elif lines in homescreen_order_string_2:
            return "checklists"
        elif lines in homescreen_order_string_3:
            return "custom text"
        else:
            return "err"

    with open('Settings.txt', 'r') as settings_file:
        for position, lines in enumerate(settings_file):
            if position in lines_to_read_1:
                if readline(lines) == "assignments":
                    print("yay") #placeholder for function to display assignments
                    break
                elif readline(lines) == "checklists":
                    print('yay 2') #placeholder for functions to display checklists
                    break
                elif readline(lines) == "custom text":
                    print("yay3") #placeholder for function to display custom text
                    break
                elif readline(lines) == "err":
                    print("err")
                    print(lines) #this is just for bug testing, to see what the system is actualy seeing. 
                    break
                else:
                    pass

#here is the .txt file I am trying to pull from:
#-----------------------------------------
#Settings:

# order of homescreen print: 
#assignments 
#checklists 
#custom text
#
# Custom Text: 
#you have no custom text!-
```

Comment: `lines` has a newline at the end of it. Remove it with `strip()`

Comment: `lines = lines.strip()`

Comment: BTW, using a plural variable name for a single line is confusing.

Comment: Note that if you use `strip`, as you should, that will also get rid of the trailing space in your lists.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing this with a dictionary that maps your commands to a function:

```
settings_file = open('Settings.txt', 'r')

def assignment_handler():
    print("yay")

def checklists_handler():
    print("yay 2")

def custom_handler():
    print("yay 3")

handlers = {
    'assignments': assignment_handler,
    'checklists': checklists_handler,
    'custom text': custom_handler
}

with open('Settings.txt', 'r') as settings_file:
    for position, line in enumerate(settings_file):
        line = line.strip()
        if position in lines_to_read_1:
            if line in handlers:
                handlers[line]()
            else:
                print( "Unknown choice", line )
```